# How to plot a ParametricPlot graph

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I want to plot `1100(r[t]-14)` vs `θ[t]`. How can I plot the functions of `r[t]` and `θ[t]` from `NDsolve`? This is my code to find `r[t]` and `θ[t]`:

```
m = 81;
g = 9.81;
h = 12;
l = 15;
d = 15;
a = (d - h) \[Pi]/180;

s = NDSolve[{(m*g*
   Sin[\[Theta][t]]) - (m*(r''[t] - r[t] ((\[Theta]'[t])^2))) == 
1100 (r[t] - 14), g*Cos[\[Theta][t]] == 
r[t]*\[Theta]''[t] + 2*r'[t]*\[Theta]'[t], \[Theta][0] == 
ArcSin[a/l], \[Theta]'[0] == 0, r[0] == 15, r'[0] == 0}, {r, \[Theta]}, {t, 0, 100}]
```

And this is code that I use to make the plot:

```
ParametricPlot[ Evaluate[{1100*(r[t] - 14), \[Theta][t]} /. s], {t, 0, 2}, PlotPoints -> 200]
```

Comment: to use `NDSolve`, all parameters used need to have numerical values.

Comment: i already use ParametricPlot but i get nothing

Comment: That is not what I meant. You can't use NDSolve as you are doing.  You need to provide numerical values for all the parameters in the ODE.

Comment: how can i provide numerical values

Comment: Well, it is your ODE. no one can guess what the numerical values for `m` and `a` and `l`. One can guess that `g=9.81` assuming we are on earth. So if you want to use NDSolve, it will not work without these parameters having a numerical value. You are the only person who knows what these should be.

Comment: i already give the value

Comment: `i already give the value` I do not see anywhere in your code where you did. This is what I am looking at on my end. ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qu2YV.png)

Comment: i get the graph of r[t] vs theta[t] by ParametricPlot but i can't get graph if i plot 1100*r[t] vs theta[t]

Comment: i soory i didn't post the code of that value

Comment: i update my code

Comment: The reason you do not see anything useful, is because the scaling  of `r[t]` and `theta[t]` is so different. You can plot each separately and see why. your `r[t]` has amplitude of about 3000, while `theta` is about 3 only.

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

m = 81;
g = 9.81;
h = 12;
l = 15;
d = 15;
a = (d - h) π/180;

s = NDSolve[
   {(m*g*Sin[θ[t]]) - (m*(r''[t] - r[t] ((θ'[t])^2))) ==
      1100 (r[t] - 14), 
    g*Cos[θ[t]] == r[t]*θ''[t] + 2*r'[t]*θ'[t],
    θ[0] == ArcSin[a/l], θ'[0] == 0, r[0] == 15, 
    r'[0] == 0},
   {r, θ}, {t, 0, 100}];

Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[{1100 (r[t] - 14), θ[t]} /. s[[1]], {t, 0, 
   tmax},
  AspectRatio -> 1,
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, t}, ColorData["Rainbow"][t]],
  PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0, tmax}}]],
 {{tmax, 10}, 1, 100, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: oh!! i get it. It only put [1]after s right

Comment: It will plot with or without the `[[1]]`; however, to see the plot you cannot use the default `AspectRatio`